# How to handle duplicate class before kotlin-android compile?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, gradle-plugin

I made a Library. It will generate the same class with different method in several library by apt.

And I write a gradle plugin to merge the duplicate class by add a Transform into android build plugin's Extension.

It works well in java project, but in Kotlin project, there comes an error before my Transform work, the error caused by the override of duplicate class, so the generate class miss many methods.

I wanna transform the code before kotlin compile. how can I do this.